# npm install -g blockchain-wallet-service

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

```
npm install -g blockchain-wallet-service
```

I have this error when I run npm install.

I've installed Visual Studio Community 2017 but not in C: Drive.
I've installed Microsoft Build tools in C:
I've tried npm config as possible I can
But this is happening again.
How can I fix it?

> AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\blockchain-wallet-service\node_modules\utf-8-validate\build\binding.sln
>   : error MSB3411:  Could not load the Visual C++ component
>   "VCBuild.exe". If the component is not installed, either 1) install
>   the Microsoft Windows SD K for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework
>   3.5, or 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.
>
> gyp ERR! build error gyp ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit
>   code: 1 gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit
>   (C:\Users\void\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13) gyp ERR! stack     at
>   ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7) gyp ERR! stack     at
>   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
>   gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134 gyp ERR! command "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe"
>   "C:\Users\void\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   "rebuild" gyp ERR! cwd
>   C:\Users\void\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\blockchain-wallet-service\node_modules\utf-8-validate
>   gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.4 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.7.0 gyp ERR! not ok
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: bufferutil@1.2.1
>   (node_modules\blockchain-wallet-service\node_modules\bufferutil): npm
>   WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: bufferutil@1.2.1 install:
>   `node-gyp rebuild` npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
>   Exit status 1 npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
>   utf-8-validate@1.2.2
>   (node_modules\blockchain-wallet-service\node_modules\utf-8-validate):
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: utf-8-validate@1.2.2
>   install: `node-gyp rebuild` npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL
>   DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

Comment: Try executing `npm install --msvs_version=2013` before your `npm install -g blockchain-wallet-service` command

Comment: I tried that way :')